# Import *.olm file into Gmail

Tags: outlook, gmail

I exported a few emails from Microsoft Outlook for Mac to an `.olm` file. I want to import it into Gmail. Is it possible to do that on gmail itself ? What is the easiest way to do that ?

Comment: Try posing on [Super User](http://superuser.com/questions) you may get help there

Comment: See if this [Link](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/164640?hl=en) can help you

Comment: @Omar : No, I have it locally and not on a server as I don't have access to that account anymore. Though, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem was that I didn't have access to the mail server anymore, but I found 2 ways to do that :

1.Export the emails (you can categorizing in Outlook to export only selected emails) to `*.olm` and then add the gmail account to your Outlook and import the file into it.

2.Add gmail account to your Outlook and move (drag and drop) the emails from the old account to your gmail account. easy !

Answer (score 6):

Arian Hosseinzadeh's solution works, but for Microsoft Outlook for Mac 2016, the key is to manually add the gmail account into your desktop Outlook as **an IMAP account**. Adding gmail following the default prompts did not work for me.

High-level steps:

- Enable IMAP for gmail.
- Add gmail into Outlook for Mac 2016 as **an IMAP account**.
- Import oml files into Outlook.
- Drag and drop imported folders into your gmail folders.

Details for the first two steps above.

- Enable IMAP for gmail. Check [this gmail support page](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en) for details. Basic steps are as follows:

  - On your computer, open Gmail.
  - In the top right, click Settings Settings.
  - Click Settings.
  - Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
  - In the "IMAP Access" section, select Enable IMAP.
  - Click Save Changes.
- Add gmail into Outlook for Mac 2016 as **an IMAP account**.

  [image]
  [image]
  [image]
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to do that.

However, the alternative is to add your outlook account to your Gmail account in gmail.com.

Setup instructions here: http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/using-microsoft-outlook-with-gmail.html

Comment: The problem is that I only have it locally as I don't have access to the server anymore.

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Answer (score 0):

If you want to choose the right way to convert OLM to Gmail then you try KDETools OLM to Gmail Converter.

•   Open Outlook for Mac on your machine and select the folder from which you want to move data

•   Right-click on that folder to select Move>>Copy to folder options.

•   A dialog box will pop up, where you need to select the newly created label name. Then, click on Copy.

•   Now, click Send/Receive button and all OLM emails can be found in Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add IMAP-enabled from Gmail account that easily sync all Gmail Items to Outlook for Mac and vice-versa.

Another way is third party tool like : http://www.recoverymails.com/olm-to-pst/mac.html
that helps you to migrate OLM items to Gmail account easily.

Answer (score 0):

In this short write-up, I will show you the best manual methods to [import OLM files to a Gmail account](https://www.recoverytools.com/blog/bulk-import-olm-to-gmail/) in bulk. as we all know that Gmail is a free email service, and outlook for mac is paid. Due to these reasons or maybe some other reasons, users are continuously importing their mac outlook data to their Gmail account by using the given steps:

**Step 1:** simply connect your Mac Outlook and Gmail accounts.

**Step 2:** And then move olm files data to the Gmail account.

If you want to know the complete steps, then check out the mentioned page. Here you will get the complete information about the process.